# How to pause a subprocess (Python 2.2.6)?

Tags: python, multithreading, video, subprocess, gpio

I'm having some trouble with a video loop I created in Python. What I want to do is play a video loop and then when a button is pressed (RPi GPIO) it will play a different video. Once, that video is finished playing it should return to playing the looped video. Everything works great with the code below except the looped video will start playing before it's time during the other videos that are playing. I'm not sure if it's a problem with how I'm doing the loop or if I need to pause the subprocess.

Thanks so much for any help and or advice ya'll can offer!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import subprocess
import time
import thread

GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings (False)

GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)

def welcome_loop():
    while True:
            global playProcess
            x = 1
            print "Play Welcome Video"
            time.sleep(.5)
            playProcess=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/loop/loop.mp4'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
            time.sleep(25)
            x += 1

def videos():
    while True:
            if GPIO.input(9):
                    print "Stop Welcome Video"
                    time.sleep(.5)
                    playProcess.stdin.write('q')             
                    time.sleep(.5)
                    print "Play Sippycup Video"
                    sippycup_video=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/sippycup.mp4'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
                    time.sleep(30)
                    sippycup_video.stdin.write('q')
                    time.sleep(.5)
                    #welcome_loop()

            if GPIO.input(10):
                    print "Stop Welcome Video"
                    time.sleep(.5)
                    playProcess.stdin.write('q')
                    time.sleep(.5)
                    print "Play Shoppingcart Video"
                    shoppingcart_video=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/shoppingcart.mp4'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
                    time.sleep(30)
                    shoppingcart_video.stdin.write('q')
                    time.sleep(.5)
                    #welcome_loop()

            if GPIO.input(11):
                    print "Stop Welcome Video"
                    time.sleep(.5)
                    playProcess.stdin.write('q')
                    time.sleep(.5)
                    print "Play Dodgeballs Video"
                    Dodgeballs_video=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/dodgeballs.mp4'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
                    time.sleep(30)
                    Dodgeballs_video.stdin.write('q')
                    time.sleep(.5)
                    #welcome_loop()

thread.start_new_thread( videos, () )
thread.start_new_thread( welcome_loop, () )

while True:
    pass

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `welcomeLoop` function will start running the welcome video every 25 seconds, no matter what is going on with the other videos. You need to set a flag when one of the other videos starting playing, so that the `welcomeLoop` function won't start replaying the welcome video over the top of them:

```
video_playing = False

def welcome_loop():
    global playProcess
    while True:
        x = 1
        if not video_playing:
            print "Play Welcome Video"
            time.sleep(.5)
            playProcess=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/loop/loop.mp4'],
                                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
        time.sleep(25)
        x += 1

def videos():
    global video_playing
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(9):
            video_playing = True  # Set the flag
            print "Stop Welcome Video"
            time.sleep(.5)
            playProcess.stdin.write('q')             
            time.sleep(.5)
            print "Play Sippycup Video"
            sippycup_video=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','Desktop/videos/sippycup.mp4'],
                                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
            time.sleep(30)
            sippycup_video.stdin.write('q')
            video_playing = False  # unset the flag
            time.sleep(.5)
            #welcome_loop()

    # Same pattern for the other videos.
```

Comment: I don't know any other way to do it that's simple enough for me, a novice, to understand. :/ It's working pretty good for me so far.

Comment: @jmcclaire If it's working for you, then feel free to stick with it. There are several things you could do to improve the design, though. If you want, you can post the code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com, and I'm sure folks would review it for you.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I tried the code you sent me, but couldn't get it to work because of me being a novice. I told you that at the beginning. You don't have to be mean about it. "lost my patience"